# Twig center form items

Tags: html, css, twig

I want to make a form and centre the items horizontally, but I did not manage to do this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DD5X.png

This is my code (everything is centered besides the form fields):

```
<div class="card top-buffer">
        <h5 class="card-header">Status</h5>

            <div class="card-body align-items-center d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="container align-items-center">
                    {% if Status[![enter image description here][1]][1]%}
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="spinner-grow text-success" role="status">
                            <span class="sr-only">Running</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <p>Running</p>
                    </div>
                    {% else %}
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        ❌ Error
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}


              <div class="row justify-content-center">
                  {{ form(notificationForm) }}

              </div>
              <div class="row justify-content-center">

               <p><i>Note: There might be a delay between status changes</i></p>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In the Browser it looks like this:
[image: Browser Code]

I tried different css things like

```
display: inline-block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

But that did not work

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I will answer this way.

I will give an example of what's happening:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center"> <!-- It tells to center what's inside -->
 <form> <!-- Form will center, but don't pass it to what's inside of it -->
   <input> Something </input> <!-- This one it's not centered because form don't tell it to -->
 </form>
```

The parent `<div class="row justify-content-center">` only says to direct children `<form>` to center. So the children of `<form>` won't.

I know you are using bootstrap or something like that, but you can understand better from [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Can you style this form `{{ form(notificationForm) }}`?

Comment: As far as I know, I can style the form() item with the <style> tag, but I can't access it

Comment: If you have a .css file that you can edit, use DevTools to see which code is being generated

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html - that's how they work. I tried some css things for the form item, but it did not work. I saw changes but I never got it to center it

Comment: Edit you question with that information, explain what you tried, what worked and what don't. Will be more easy. And try to take a screenshot from DevTools to show the code of that form

Comment: I added a screenshot

Comment: How do you create this form  {{ form(notificationForm) }}?

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-forms-in-controllers - like this

Comment: I can't fully understand the docs, I never tried Symfony before but i found this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiC_TGdMINc - I think part of it it's what you have done, the other one he explain how you can give a css class to an input and also he show how it renders on DevTools. If you could do that, then I can tell you how to center the others input. I don't know why  your DevTools don't show everything.